# Facebook javascript SDK: FB.ui stream.publish method on Blackberry

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, blackberry, fbjs

I've been developing a web-based app with Facebook integration, to run in mobile browsers. It uses the stream.publish method of the FB.ui javascript object. The app is working correctly on iPhone and Droid, but I'm having problems on Blackberry.

Specifically, when I call the stream.publish command, a Facebook dialog appears, overlaying the page, but it just shows the animated .gif progress bars, and never replaces them with the actual content of the Publish dialog. This happens in the native Blackberry browser, and also in Opera Mini on the device.

Is this just a limitation of the platform, or has anyone successfully used the Publish dialog via javascript on a Blackberry?

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: Which version of BlackBerry OS ? Because, before version 6, Javascript support is really bad.

Comment: It's version 4.7. And it sounds like even at version 5.0, I might still be out of luck?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this too. Also, FB.UI({method:'apprequests'}) for invite friends is also resulting in the same state..